# How do I use an SVG as a background image in CSS custom property?

Tags: html, css, svg, blazor

I am using Blazor to create a Web App. The SVG is displaying a pipe which the user can interact with. The pipe can be moved and most importantly stretched in its x-axis. I have written CSS which uses the SVG as a background image to repeat it in a correct way when it is being resized.

This is my CSS:

```
<style>
    .resizable-pipe {
        height: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: var(--background-image);
        display: block;
        background-size: auto 100%;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
</style>
```

I have got it working with the following:

```
<div class="resizable-pipe" style="--background-image: @ViewModel.BackgroundImage" />
```

`@ViewModel.BackgroundImage` represents a string which contains the SVG. The problem is that this method is not maintanable because when we want to e.g. change the SVG or do something different with it, it is a lot of work.

My idea was to put the SVG into the HTML and try to reference it with `defs`. Unfortunately this doesn't work.

```
<svg id="b" data-name="Ebene 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="10" viewBox="0 0 28 10">
    <defs>
        <g id="c" data-name="Ebene 1">
            <g>
                <rect x=".0005" width="27.9945" height="10" fill="@ViewModel.BackgroundColor" />
                <path d="M0,9.35H2.5059l4.1256-3.5808c.4895-.4248,.4895-1.1136,0-1.5385L2.5059,.65H0L4.7886,4.8063c.1233,.107,.1233,.2805,0,.3875L0,9.35Z" fill="@ViewModel.ArrowColor" />
                <path d="M7.0386,9.35h2.5059l4.1256-3.5808c.4895-.4248,.4895-1.1136,0-1.5385L9.5445,.65h-2.5059l4.7886,4.1563c.1233,.107,.1233,.2805,0,.3875l-4.7886,4.1563Z" fill="@ViewModel.ArrowColor" />
                <path d="M14.0172,9.35h2.5059l4.1256-3.5808c.4895-.4248,.4895-1.1136,0-1.5385L16.5231,.65h-2.5059l4.7886,4.1563c.1233,.107,.1233,.2805,0,.3875l-4.7886,4.1563Z" fill="@ViewModel.ArrowColor" />
                <path d="M21.0314,9.35h2.4952l4.1079-3.5808c.4874-.4248,.4874-1.1136,0-1.5385L23.5266,.65h-2.4952l4.7681,4.1563c.1228,.107,.1228,.2805,0,.3875l-4.7681,4.1563Z" fill="@ViewModel.ArrowColor" />
                <rect x=".0005" y="9" width="27.9946" height="1" fill="#262626" />
                <rect x=".0005" width="27.9946" height="1" fill="#262626" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </defs>
    <rect width="28" height="10" class="resizable-pipe" style="--background-image: #c" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You showed us what does work, but not what doesn't work - show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: I showed you the code that doesn't work. It is the code on the bottom. The SVG is not being displayed.

Comment: I see it now - you are trying to get the `rect` inside the SVG to use a style definition to set a CSS custom property to reference the `def` with `id=c` ?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was trying to archive.

Comment: I don't see how putting the **SVG** in the HTML is very maintainable.

Comment: @RohitGupta Do you have another idea on how to tackle the problem? It is way more maintanable than having to convert the SVG into a working string every time we change it I guess.